# xterm behaving strangely when called recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I wanted to troll one of my friends, just a little joke, nothing serious.
I wanted to write a recursive python program, that opens a terminal, and starts itself in it. This would lead to a non-stop opening of new `xterm`-windows.

I thought that if you close the original window, all windows would have to close, because they are child processes from the previous one. I tried this manually, opened xterm, executed `xterm` in it, and another window opened, I redid the two times, but when I closed the first newly created terminal window, only the second window was closed. The third one just stayed there.

Where is this behaviour coming from an how can I avoid it in python?
I'm on Raspbian, so any Debian solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm on Raspbian, so any Debian solution would be highly appreciated

Comment: The original window is only the direct parent of the first child window.  All the other child windows are actually grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.  If you want the original window to be the direct parent of all the other windows, then spawn the new xterms in a loop instead of recursively.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes.